# what is the most efficient way to pass in this bool to this function?

Tags: c++, performance, pointers, memory, boolean

I have a function in another class that will be being called every frame and I want to know the best way to pass this boolean value in. What is the best way to do this? I have two options and I'm not sure what the best one would be to use? Or if there is a better way to do this altogether? The bool in question is the 'decrease bool'

Option 1:

```
Class 1:
void Update()
{
SkillSelectionArrow skillArrow
skillArrow.Update(deltaTime, &skills.weight, true);
}

Class 2:
void SkillSelectionArrow::Update(float * deltaTime, int *valueToBeChanged, bool decrease)
{
    if (this->CheckSpecificCollision(mouse) && input->getMouseLeftDown() == true)
    {
        decrease == true ? valueToBeChanged++ : valueToBeChanged--;     
    }
}
```

or would initialising a bool be more efficient and passing this in for example:

Option 2:

```
Class 1:
void Update()
{
SkillSelectionArrow skillArrow
bool decrease = true;
skillArrow.Update(deltaTime, &skills.weight, &decrease);
}

Class 2:
void SkillSelectionArrow::Update(float * deltaTime, int *valueToBeChanged, bool *decrease)
{
    if (this->CheckSpecificCollision(mouse) && input->getMouseLeftDown() == true)
    {
        *decrease == true ? valueToBeChanged++ : valueToBeChanged--;        
    }
}
```

Thank you

Comment: It depends on what you want to do further with the bool. If you want, you may as well collect it in a `const bool& decrease`. There's not much memory saving (or any other optimisation) which can be applied there as its just 1 bit

Comment: Unless you're interested in the modified value, passing a pointer (or reference) to  a primitive is a pessimisation.

Comment: I very much doubt that the way you pass a `bool` will actually matter in any measureble way. Don't worry about it. Just pass by value.

Comment: @JesperJuhl, I Concur. The OP probably is confused between pass by value and by pointer and the memory it will take :)

Answer (score 3):

Pass by value is usually better for small objects. The pointer is likely to be bigger than the object itself.

The general rule is to pass by value if the size of the object is less than `2*sizeof(void*)`. (see https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#Rf-in)

`float` and `int` is thus usually passed by value (unless you want to modify them in the function!).

Note that the performance impact is likely to be very small, probably negligible. More important is to be able to understand the intent of the method. When you pass by pointer, it looks as though you want to modify the object, but for the boolean you do not want to do that, right?

Comment: `2*sizeof(void*)` is just a guideline, which is a good rule of thumb.  But, if it is a performance concern best to profile, and measure.  On my system, it's bigger than that (in some cases even as high as `32*sizeof(void*)` to `64*sizeof(void*)` as the break even).  And the performance is much better for some highly used routines (which are getting inlined) passing by value rather than by pointer or by reference.  And for a sink parameter, our dev lead wants everyone to pass by value.

Comment: Hi, yes my intent with the function is to pass in the 'valueToBeChanged' into the other class to then alter this value. The bool will just be to decide on how this value will be changed either to be added to or taken away from but will always remain the same either false or true from the beginning

Comment: Im a little confused when you talk about '2*sizeof(void*)'. When you say this do you mean for my example above I would do 2 * sizeof(&decrease) and as this = 8 and 2 * sizeof(false) = 2 I should then pass by value as it is less than it? Thank you for your help this has been great!

Comment: @user12322186 size of `void* ` is the memory size of a pointer in your computer. If your computer have a 32bit architecture, it is 4 byte, and if it is 64bit 8 byte (these are the most usual ones. In comparison, an int is usually 4 byte, and a double 8 byte, so both these should, by the rule of thumb, be passed by value. You check the pointer size by calling `std::cout << sizeof(void*)`.